# Converting a column from a schemaRDD to a string array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to convert a column that is a string array into a string by concatenating it's values but some how I can't relate to that specific column as an Array of Strings:

```
val converted = jsonFiles.map(line=> {line(7).asInstanceOf[Array[String]] })
converted.collect
```

And I end up with:

> 4/11/23 10:40:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: What is a `column` ? `line(7)` gives back an is an ArrayBuffer, you can't turn it into `Array[String]`

Comment: I'm having a similar problem -- I've tried to cast my column both as asInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[(Int,String)]] and asInstanceOf[Iterable[(Int,String)]] for my application, but when I attempt to map that RDD to one using that column, it gives the error "GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2"

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand correctly what you are looking for, but I'll try. You need to read a line of String and split the String into array by spaces

```
val converted = jsonFiles.map(line=> {line(7).split(" ")})
converted.collect
```

The problem here is that (depends what you are doing) "Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)" should be as a one String, not splitted. To do this we need:

- split string as " " to array
- create array from first 4 columns
- add to this array merged string from the right subarray

code:

```
val columns = line(7).split(" ")
columns.take(4) :+ columns.drop(4).mkString(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up casting it ti Itreable[String] and called mkString. Worked perfect :)

Comment: How do we do this for TUPLES?  I have a column with an array of (Int,String), so I cannot run mkString on it, even after I cast my column to either ArrayBuffer or Iterable

Answer (score 0):

I ended up casting it to Itreable[String] and called it's mkString.